# CGI.escape space problem. Need for generate oauth signature for Magento

Tags: ruby, oauth

I try to generate oauth signature for authorization api with Magento. I found the problem because `CGI.escape` generate `+` for space instead of `%20` for params. Anyone know how to correct it.

I try to use `URI.escape` too but it only convert space to %20 other thing was not be converted

```rb
CGI.escape("2019-06-11 00:00:00")
```

got `2019-06-11+00%3A00%3A00`
expect `2019-06-11%2000%3A00%3A00`

Comment: Magento docs ask for parameter encoding, where `+` should be okay for a space. Have you tried it and gotten an error (in which case, please edit the error into your question), or are you just assuming `+` won't work? (Also, use `CGI::escape`, as `URI::escape` has been deprecated.)

Comment: I try already + won't work. Anyway on my question I am sure I mention I used CGI.escape